# Using tikz, how would I draw a heptagon with area 7?

Tags: tikz-pgf

How could I draw, using tikz, a regular heptagon of area 7 sq.units?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Please show us that code ...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A quick search points to `shapes.geometric`. I let you do the math to find the appropriate radius ;-)

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric}

\begin{document}

{\def\PolyRadius{2cm}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    % Remove next line to remove the red circle
    \draw[red] (0,0) circle [radius=\PolyRadius];
    \node[regular polygon,draw,regular polygon sides = 7,minimum size=2*\PolyRadius] at (0,0) {};
  \end{tikzpicture}
}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5):

For regular polygon of `n` sides with area `S`, length from center to a vertex `r`, we have [the formula](https://vi.wikipedia.org/wiki/%C4%90a_gi%C3%A1c_%C4%91%E1%BB%81u)

[image]

The TikZ code is using `foreach` inside one `\draw` command. The unit here is `cm` - the default unit of TikZ.

[image]

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
% for maths
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node{$S=\dfrac{nr^2\sin\left(\frac{360}{n}\right)}{2}$ \quad implies\quad $r=\sqrt{\dfrac{2S}{n\sin\left(\frac{360}{n}\right)}}$};
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\def\n{7}    % number of sides of a heptagon
\def\S{7}    % the area of that heptagon
\pgfmathsetmacro{\k}{360/\n}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\r}{(sqrt(2*\S))/(\n*sin(\k))}
\draw[violet] (90:\r) 
foreach \i[parse=true] in {1,...,\n-1}  {--({90+\k*\i}:\r)}--cycle;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```