# `\foreach` does not understand constants in `declare function`: a bug?

Tags: tikz-pgf, foreach

In relation with [an answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/616342/140722), I see that `\foreach` does not understand a constant (`n`) in `declare function`. Is it a bug? or there is another proper way of code for this situation?

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\def\n{7}    % number of sides of a heptagon
\pgfmathsetmacro{\k}{360/\n}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\r}{2}
\draw[cyan] (90:\r) foreach \i in {1,...,\n}  {--({90+\k*\i}:\r)}--cycle;
\end{tikzpicture}

% This does not work! Uncomment this tikzpicture to get a MWE
\begin{tikzpicture}[declare function={n=7;r=2;k=360/n;}]
\draw (90:r) foreach \i in {1,...,n} {--({90+k*\i}:r)}--cycle;
\end{tikzpicture}

% This works, but not natural! Is that a bug of \foreach ?
\begin{tikzpicture}[declare function={n=7;r=2;k=360/n;}]
\pgfmathsetmacro\m{n}
\draw (90:r) foreach \i in {1,...,\m} {--({90+k*\i}:r)}--cycle;
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I have always found it confusing to use constants in TikZ. I am also very much interested in how `declare function` constants can be used and what the equivalent pgf set command is. I think `\def\n{7}` is bad because it can collide with packages - so `newcommand` is preferred but seem silly for a constant.

Comment: Yes, `\newcommand\n{7}` is better than `\def\n{7}`. Both of them can be use in `standalone` pdf picture that later it can be embbed into LaTeX document via `\includegraphics`. However, what I think TikZ' syntax **should** allow `\draw (90:r) foreach \i in {1,...,n} {--({90+k*\i}:r)}--cycle;
` after declare constant/function `[declare function={n=7;r=2;k=360/n;}]`

Comment: TikZ runs almost everything through `\pgfmathparse`, which will recognize n as a math function.  Evidently the foreach parser does not.  Nor will it recognize (7) or 3+4.

Comment: Also, inside an environment (tikzpicture) I would argue that \def is better.  It doesn't really matter if it is already defined, as the new definition will be lost when done.  OTOH, \gdef and \xdef names should be reserved in the preamble using \newcommand.

Comment: @JohnKormylo In my code, TikZ/PGF parsers recognizes `k` and `r`. So `foreach` parser seems not as smart as other PGF parsers. It is unbalanced!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since PGF 3.1.2 (I think) you can use the `parse=true` option of `\foreach`.

[image]

In this situation you have to wrap `n` in parentheses so that `\foreach` parses it as a mathematical expression. Without parentheses `\foreach` will assume that you want an alphabetical loop `a,...,n` but since the lower limit is not alphabetical it will break.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[declare function={n=7;r=2;k=360/n;}]
  \draw (90:r) foreach \i [parse=true] in {1,...,(n)} { -- ({90+k*\i}:r) } --cycle;
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you very much! It works as I expected on TikZ/PGF syntax. I just wonder that * wrapping n in parentheses* is documented in the pgfmanual.pdf or not?

Comment: @BlackMild It's impossible to document all edge cases. And the manual is more than long enough already. Nobody reads it anyway.

Comment: At least I know a girl who printed out and read the pgfmanual. She must be in love with TikZ ^^